# X,Y Plot Excel Question

Tags: excel

Im sure there is an easy way to do this, but in Excel (specifically the 2010 version)
Is there a way when selecting data for an X,Y scatter plot to select every like....15 or X pieces of data

So like pretend I was selecting a huge column for a list for the X points, is there a way to do EVERY 15...instead of just all. Because sometimes I have a thousand data points and I can't click every 15 lol that'd take forever.

Thanks

Comment: Is this more of a SuperUser question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the data, add a column containing `=IF(MOD(ROW(B1),15)=0,1,0)`

Select the rows which have 1 in this column

Cut/paste elsewhere

Plot them

Comment: Ah awesome! thanks. How would I determine what column im doing the data on?